# Find unbiased for $\theta$ given a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, \theta]$. Let $Y_{(1)} = \min(Y_1,\ldots, y_n)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Show that $\hat{\theta_1} = (n+1) ~y_{(1)}$ is unbiased for $\theta$.

So far what I got is 
$f(y) = 1/\theta$ for , $0 \le y \le \theta$

So $F(y) = P[Y \le y] = \displaystyle \int_\theta^y 1/\theta dy = y/\theta |_\theta^y = 1 - y/\theta$.

Then $g_{(1)} (y) = n [ -y/\theta]^{(n-1)} (y/\theta)$

Are these right? If so, how to go from here? If so, could you show your approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W$ be the minimum. The minimum is $\gt w$ iff all the $Y_i$ are $\gt w$.

The probability a particular $Y_i$ is $\gt w$ is, for $0\lt w\lt \theta$, equal to $1-w/\theta$. Thus the probability all the $Y_i$ are $\gt w$ is $(1-w/\theta)^n$, and therefore 
$$F_W(w)=1-(1-w/\theta)^n,$$
(for $0\lt w\lt \theta$).

Thus the minimum has density function $(1/\theta)n(1-w/\theta)^{n-1}$ in our interval. The mean of $W$ is therefore
$$\int_0^{\theta} w(1/\theta)n(1-w/\theta)^{n-1}\,dw.$$

Integrate. I suggest making the substitution $x=1-w/\theta$. Integration by parts will also work well.

If you know a formula for expectation in terms of an integral that involves the cumulative distribution function, use that, it will be somewhat simpler.

**Added:** Let $1-w/\theta=x$. Then $-dw/\theta=dx$, so $dw=-\theta \,dx$. Also, $w=(1-x)\theta$. Substitute. We get
$$\int_{x=1}^0 (1-x)\theta(1/\theta)nx^{n-1}(-\theta)\,dx.$$
Simplify a bit. We end up with
$$\int_0^1 (\theta n)(x^{n-1}-x^n)\,dx.$$
Integrate. The integral of $x^{n-1}-x^n$ from $0$ to $1$ is $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$, which is $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$. Multiply by $n\theta$. we get $\frac{\theta}{n+1}$.

So the expectation of $W$ is $\frac{\theta}{n+1}$. Thus the expectation of our estimator $(n+1)W$ is $\theta$. It follows that $(n+1)W$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

Comment: Can you show me the integration?

Comment: OK, it will take a few minutes. I cannot do it in a comment, editing is too hard.

Comment: why does the first integral goes from x=1 to 0?

Comment: We made the substitution $x=1-w/\theta$. So when $w=0$, then $x=1$ and when $w=\theta$, then $x=0$. Of course in the next line I put the $1$ where it belongs, on top, changing sign. That cancelled the minus sign obtained from the derivative in the substitution.

Comment: Another way to do the integration is by parts, $u=w$, and $dv=(n/\theta)(1-w/\theta)^{n-1}dw$.

Comment: Under the same uniform distribution on the same interval, how to approach $Y_{(n)} = max(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ and show that $\hat{\theta_2} = (n+1)/n Y_{(n)}$ is unbiased for $\theta$? If this is difficult to answer, I will open a new post

Comment: Similar but easier. Let $Z$ be the maximum. We have $Z\le z$ iff all the $Y_i$ are $\le z$. For $0\lt z\lt 1$ this has probability $(z/\theta)^n$. So the density is $(n/\theta^n)z^{n-1}$. For the expectation, multiply by $z$ and integrate. The integral is much easier than the previous one. You should get $\frac{n}{n+1}$.

Comment: Nicolas: I have a related post which is related my question I add above for $Y_{(n)} = max(Y_1, ..., Y_n)$...Please take a look at the following link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770159/find-unbiased-for-theta-given-a-uniform-distribution-on-the-interval-0-th

Comment: Nicolas: I just got myself into a hole: For $$P[Y_i \le Y] = 1 - y/\theta$$ 
Then for $ P[Y_{(1)} < y] = 1 - [1-F_{(Y_i)} (y)]^n$ which should equal to $1 - [1-(1-y/\theta)]^n = 1 - [y/\theta]^n$ However, $F_{Y_{(1)}}(y)$ is supposed to be $1 - (1-y/\theta)^n$....where is my derivation goes wrong?

Comment: It is done in my answer. I don't know why you are insisting on writing $P(Y_i\le Y)$, what is $Y$? If you want $\Pr(Y_i\le y)$, that is $\frac{y}{\theta}$, not $1-y/theta$. But for the minimum, it is best  to note that the minimum is $\gt y$ if all the $Y_i$ are $\gt $y$. This has probability $(1-y/\theta)^n$. Now we have the probability that the minimum is $\gt y$. For the complementary event, subtract from $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are close.
The cdf of $Y_{(1)} =\min(y_1, …, y_n)$ looks like: 
$$F_Y(y)=1-(1-F_{y(1)}(y))^n=1-\left(1-\frac{y}{\theta}\right)^n,$$ then the pdf $$w_Y(y)=\frac{n}{\theta }\left(1-\frac{y}{\theta }\right)^{n-1}.$$
So $$\mathbb{E}\{\hat{\theta}\}=(n+1)\int_0^\theta y \  w_Y(y)\mathrm dy=(n+1)\int_0^\theta y \  \frac{n}{\theta }\left(1-\frac{y}{\theta }\right)^{n-1}\mathrm dy=\theta$$
And since the mean value of your estimator ($\hat{\theta}$) equals to $\theta$ it is unbiased.

Comment: Can you show me the integration since I do not how to solve it ?